# AngularJS and Ruby on Rails - Uploading multiple files directly to Amazon S3

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm writing an app where users can write Notes, and each note can have many files attached to it.

I would like users to be able to click 'Browse', select multiple files, which will be uploaded when the user clicks 'Save Note'.

I want these files to be uploaded directly into Amazon S3 (or some other cloud storage solution?) **without going through my server**, so I don't have to worry about uploads blocking my server.

What is the best way to accomplish this?
I have seen many examples to upload directly into Amazon S3, but none of them support **multiple files**. Will I somehow have to do this all in Javascript by looping through a collection of files selected with the Browse button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your javascript residing in the browser could make HTTP RESTful calls to AWS and store data in S3, but then you would be exposing the security credentials to connect to AWS in the script.. not good.

I guess the only way is to process it thru a web-server which can securely access AWS and store the notes.. or, you could just write those notes to a local disk (where the webserver sits), and schedule tools like s3cmd to automatically synch them with S3 buckets.